# Is there a way to send a Ctrl+D via software in to python stdin?

Tags: python, ply

Im using `lexer.input(sys.stdin.read())` to be able to write in console with freedom and to tokenize if´s, for´s etc in lexer ,but I want that when someone write "exit" it send CTRL+D so sys.stdin.read() stop reading and end my program .
Tried to do this in my code:

```
lexer.input(sys.stdin.read())
for tok in lexer:
    if tok.value == "exit":
        sys.stdin.read(0o4)
```

But it didnt exit. The 004 is because in this page https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-July/165325.html they say what is the code for CTRL+D but it doesnt say how to send it.

Comment: What is `lexer`? (i.e. how did you create it?)

Comment: How about `sys.exit()` or putting things into functions from which you can just `return`?

Comment: @KlausD.: `sys.stdin.read()` doesn’t return until the EOF, so there’s no way to detect `"exit"` like this to begin with.

Comment: Try use `exit()`

Comment: Well, that's why I shouldn't answer without testing. Got the order of arguments to takewhile wrong. I made it an answer, after a bit of testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.stdin.read()` will read all of stdin before returning, so the input function in

```
lexer.input(sys.stdin.read())
```

cannot be prematurely terminated by anything done inside the lexer. The entire input has been read before `lexer.input` has even been called.

You can read up to (but not including) the first line containing `exit` with the following:

```
from itertools import takewhile
lexer.input(''.join(takewhile(lambda line: 'exit' not in line, sys.stdin)))
```

although I'd personally prefer something like

```
from itertools import takewhile
notdone = lambda line: not line.lstrip().startswith('exit')
lexer.input(''.join(takewhile(notdone, sys.stdin)
```

That won't get confused by lines which happen to contain `exit` in the middle of something, but will still stop if it hits a line whose first word just starts with `exit`. (Fortunately, the only such words in standard English are simple variations on the word `exit` itself.)

Comment: Thank you very much rici (again by the way), just one other favor, can you explain me how does that work? Im really very python newbie and I would love to understand it as much as possible

Comment: It's all about generators. A file (such as `sys.stdin`) is a generator which produces lines from the file. `takewhile` takes a function and a generator and uses the function to decide when to stop generating (so its result is a truncated generator.) `''.join(...)` concatenates the values from a generator, and therefore forces all its values to be computed. Understanding generators is an essential part of understanding Python; look around on http://docs.python.org for a good introduction.

Comment: @Sebas: i didn't find a good intro on the official site, but I'm sure I've seen one. However, google found me this, which doesn't look awful: http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_generators.php. Sadly, the signal-to-noise ratio on the modern internet is really low. Maybe your professor/TA can help. Good luck.

Comment: By the way, lambda is just way to write an anonymous function. (Functions are values in Python; that's also important to understand.) Think of `lambda x: ...` as kind of like `def <anonymous>(x): return ...`

Comment: @Sebas: This is the one I was thinking of: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html. Skip the introduction and read it again when you finish the rest of the document. That document was written for Python 2 and while it's been updated, it might still have some things which don't work on Python 3; still, it's a good introduction to the concepts. Again, good luck. And sorry there aren't more good resources. (Peor aún en castellano.)